# iPad: PDF in UIWebView has sometimes a blank first page (why and how to solve?)

Tags: xcode, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

My app for the iPad shows PDF-files by using a UIWebView. But sometimes when I click on several pdfs in a row, the first page of a pdf is blank suddenly. When I reopen the same pdf a second time, the first page is normal again. This happens from time to time and is not just linked to a specific pdf file.

Any ideas or did you had similar issues? Solutions? :/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you mean the first page is blank but the rest of the document is ok? or you get a blank page somehow added in front of the document?

Comment: Absolute, the rest of the document is totally normal. Just the first page is sometimes blank...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing neither code, nor the PDFS, I would bet for a memory related issue, since you say this happens when showing several PDFs in a row. Indeed, `UIWebView` is highly optimized as to memory usage and keeps in memory only relevant parts of the page, so it could be that somehow your first page is unloaded.

You can check if this is the case by adding some `NSLog` traces to `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in your app delegate. If you see the trace logged just before the blank page issue appears, then this would be a hint that it might be a memory problem.

If my hypothesis is right, then a fix would be forcing the web page to refresh its content. Or you might try a workaround just to make this particular use case (quickly moving through multiple PDFs documents in a row) work. In both cases, I would need more detail to suggest any possible implementation.